# ip monitor : responding to events

Tags: shell-script, networking, ip

I want to run a script in response to certain network events and to do this I am monitoring network routes using

```
ip monitor route dev enp3s0
```

`ip monitor` waits for events and prints them as they occur.

I want these events to trigger another script.

I have what I think is a crude solution :

```
 ip monitor route dev enp3s0 > /var/log/ipmon.log
```

and then

```
 while inotifywait /var/log/ipmon.log; do something;done;
```

But how can I `do something` without using `inotifywait`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feed its output to a shell (or any other language) loop:

```
ip monitor route dev enp3s0 | while read event; do
    case "$event" in
    'Deleted default'*)
        ...
        ;;
    'local '*)
        ...
        ;;
    ...)
        ...
        ;;
    ...
    esac
done
```